# Cannot Read for Each property of null while displaying Gallery Images

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

This is my Product method for displaying all the PRODUCTS at the Home PAGE WITH respect to its Categories

```
//GET Products DEtails
router.get('/:category/:product',function(req,res){

  var galleryImages=null;

  models.Product.findOne({
    where:{slug:req.params.product}
  })
  .then(function(product){
    var galleryDir='public/product_images/' + product.id + '/gallery';
    fs.readdir(galleryDir,function(files){
      galleryImages=files;

      res.render('product',{
        title:product.title,
        p:product,
        galleryImages:galleryImages,


      })
    })
  })

});
```

This is mine Product.ejs file for displaying it the P.Images is working above but the forEach loop is not working Cannot read property forEach of Null the Path for mine Gallery images is Correct

```
<% include layouts/header  %>

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="page-header"><%= p.title %></h1>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
        <img class="spi" src="/product_images/<%= p.id %>/<%= p.images %>" alt="">
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
        <p><%= p.desc %></p>
        <p>$<%= parseFloat(p.price).toFixed(2) %></p>  
        <p><a href="/cart/add/<%= p.slug %>">Add To Cart</a></p>      
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="gallery">
            <% galleryImages.forEach(function(images){ %>
            <% if (images != "thumbs") { %>
            <li>
                <!--<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="/product_images/<%= p.id %>/gallery/<%= images %>"> -->
                    <img src="/product_images/<%= p.id %>/gallery/thumbs/<%= images %>" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
            <% } %>
            <% }); %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- 
- will gave Content Where as = will gave Html <P>tag in the Browser</P>  -->
<% include layouts/footer  %>
```

Comment: Please put the output of `files` from `galleryImages=files;`.

Comment: At which line bro!! where galleryImages:galleryImages i have tried to change it into files but its not working

Comment: after this `fs.readdir(galleryDir,function(files){`

Comment: i dont understand you bro how to put the output of **files**

Comment: I am getting null when i have res.json(files) bro!!

Comment: Then its returning null and that's why you are getting error , coz you can loop through null value , it should be atleast array or make it blank array if its null.

Comment: How can i do that please tell me bro this is mine first uni project

Answer (score 0):

This is my ***products.js*** after try. It worked

```
/*
 * GET product details by category
 */
router.get('/:category/:product', function (req,res){

    Product.findOne({slug: req.params.product}, function (err, product) {
    if(!product) { //if product not exist in db
        return res.status(404).send('Product not found');
    }else{
        var galleryDir = 'public/product_images/' + product._id + '/gallery';

           fs.readdir(galleryDir, function (err, files) {
               if (err) {
                   console.log(err);
               } else {
                   galleryImages = files;

                   res.render('product', {
                       title: product.title,
                       p: product,
                       galleryImages: galleryImages
                   });
               }
           }); 
    }
    });
});
```